# How can I parse this JSON Object for Bing search API

Tags: java, json, bing-api

I have a JSON Object for a Bing search API result that structured as:

```
{"d":
{"results":[
{"__metadata":{"uri":"***","type":"***"},"ID":"***","Title":"***","Description":"***","DisplayUrl":"***","Url":"***"},

//repeated for 50 array items

     ]
,"__next":https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Web?Query=\u0027microsoft\u0027&$skip=50"}}

}
}
```

I could parse the 50 array items to get the search result URLs. But this is only for the first page of the Bing search result. I want to get the search result URLs in all the pages. I have couple of questions but all at the same issue.

1) How can I loop over the search result pages? Is there any way I can get the number of results from the Bing JSON object? 
2) how can I know that I reached the last page? 
3) How can I get the last JSON object which is:

```
"__next":https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Web?Query=\u0027microsoft\u0027&$skip=50"}}
```

Comment: I did and could extract the URLs but I have no idea how to iterate over the Bing search result pages and how to extract the last item. Please, reread my question.

Comment: Why not? Seems like the intention is that you make a new RESTful call to that URL and fetch the next 50 results. If you want to get more I'd look for a way in the API to get more results in one go.

Comment: @user2192774, sorry, I have read the title only.

Comment: @Gimby Bing allows for 50 results/page as a maximum. If I want to make another RESTful call for every page, I want to do this programmatically. So, how can I know how many pages I have so I repeat the call as the number of pages.

Comment: If you use one of the plain vanilla JSON libraries that don't try to return a "POJO" fully formed, you will parse the JSON into a "tree" of Maps and Lists (though the given API may have their own classes of Maps and Lists).  It is a simple matter to "navigate" from the "root" of the tree to a List of URLs or whatever and then iterate through that List.  If you need to know how many elements are in the List, just ask it.

Comment: As to how to get more than 50 elements from Bing, that's between you and Bing and has nothing to do with JSON.  Usually there's a way to specify (in your request) the starting offset and max number of elements in a list (JSON array), when the list may be over-long.